# Import multiple csv files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame where 1st column same in all csv and no headers of data just file name

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Import multiple CSV files into pandas and concatenate into one DataFrame where 1st column same in all csv and no headers of data just file name.

In all CSV only file name described the meaning of data in it.
No header in all CSV files.
1st column is common in all CSV files.

how to merge all CSV files to one dataset in python.
code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

path= "....\\data"
os.chdir(path)
results = pd.DataFrame()

for counter, current_file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.csv")):
    namedf = pd.read_csv(current_file, header=None)
    print(namedf)
    results = results.merge(namedf, on='0')

results.to_csv('Combined.csv', index=None, header=None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you wrote *no headers*, I assume that reading should be performed rather
with `header=None`. Using `header=filename` is a very weird concept.

I assume that you have first 2 input DataFrames something like below:

```
   0     1     2
0  A  Bbb1  Ccc1
1  B  Bbb2  Ccc2
2  C  Bbb3  Ccc3
3  D  Bbb4  Ccc4

   0     1     2
0  A  Ddd1  Eee1
1  B  Ddd2  Eee2
2  C  Ddd3  Eee3
3  D  Ddd4  Eee4
```

with the same content in the first column.

As I understand, you want to join (actually *merge*) them **horizontally**,
on common values in the first column.

To merge first 2 DataFrames, say *df* and *df2* you can do:

```
df = pd.merge(df, df2, on=[0], how='outer')
df.columns = [ n for n in range(len(df.columns)) ]
```

Then the merged content is back in *df* and columns are renamed to
consecutive integers:

```
   0     1     2     3     4
0  A  Bbb1  Ccc1  Ddd1  Eee1
1  B  Bbb2  Ccc2  Ddd2  Eee2
2  C  Bbb3  Ccc3  Ddd3  Eee3
3  D  Bbb4  Ccc4  Ddd4  Eee4
```

This way you don't repeat the first column (the merge key).

So your loop to read and merge source files can be something like:

```
for counter, current_file in enumerate(glob.glob("*.csv")):
    print(f'{counter}: {current_file}')
    if counter == 0:
        df = pd.read_csv(current_file, header=None)
    else:
        df2 = pd.read_csv(current_file, header=None)
        df = pd.merge(df, df2, on=[0], how='outer')
        df.columns = [ n for n in range(len(df.columns)) ]
```